# If I have the music track and a music+vocals track, is it possible to seperate the vocals?

Tags: audio, audition

I have two audio tracks, one contains vocals and has background instrumental music. I also have a second audio track which contains just the straight background music.

I would like to know (if it is possible) how to extract the vocals from the first track. Possibly by comparing it with that of the second and extracting the perhaps by finding differences in pitch/tone from the first track.

I have a subscription to Adobe CC master collection, so I have access to Adobe Audition CC, I'm hoping there's a way to do this using that program, but I can purchase another program if it can only be done in another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the music track is identical to the music in the vocal+music track, then you could invert the phase of the music track and mix it with the combined track, which (algebraically, at least) is the same as subtracting it from the v+m track.

You may find that some additional compression, level shifting or EQ was done to the v+m track, which would make the subtraction less than perfect.

Comment: Yes the music track is identical to the music in the vocals+music track. This sounds like it should work...

Comment: It definitely worked. Like you said it's not perfect, the drum beats aren't quite silent, but it definitely gives me something a lot easier to work with. Thanks!